# Apache: how to rewrite a URL-encoded path that includes slashes?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-auth-openidc

I have a logout link that looks like:

```
https://example.com/oauth2callback?logout=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Floggedout.html
```

In other words, `/oauth2callback?logout=https://example.com/loggedout.html`, but it has to be URL-encoded. This is a bit of a handful, so I want the user to see `https://example.com/keycloak/logout` instead.

To do this I've added a rewrite rule:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
RewriteRule ^/keycloak/logout$ /oauth2callback?logout=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Floggedout.html [L,QSA]
```

This doesn't work. The Apache log shows, with rewrite debugging:

```
    init rewrite engine with requested uri /keycloak/logout, referer: https://example.com/
    ...
    applying pattern '^/keycloak/logout$' to uri '/keycloak/logout', referer: https://example.com/
    rewrite '/keycloak/logout' -> '/oauth2callback?logout=httpsAFFexample.comFloggedout.html', referer: https://example.com/
    split uri=/oauth2callback?logout=httpsAFFexample.comFloggedout.html -> uri=/oauth2callback, args=logout=httpsAFFexample.comFloggedout.html, referer: https://example.com/
    local path result: /oauth2callback, referer: https://example.com/
    prefixed with document_root to /var/www1/oauth2callback, referer: https://example.com/
    go-ahead with /var/www1/oauth2callback [OK], referer: https://example.com/
```

This ends up as a `404` - I can't tell if Apache is doing this because of the forward slashes, or because Keycloak doesn't understand the query string. Note that `/oauth2callback` is not a real location on the server - it's handled internally by `mod_auth_openidc`. I thought this might be a problem, so I've also tried the `PT` flag, but it didn't help.

I've tried lots of variations of this, with `AllowEncodedSlashes` either `On` or `NoDecode`, and other flags, including `R` and `B`. The logs for all of these show that Apache is producing a query string that looks like `logout=httpsAFFexample.comFloggedout.html`, so the encoding seems to be lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> AllowEncodedSlashes On
> RewriteRule ^/keycloak/logout$ /oauth2callback?logout=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Floggedout.html [L,QSA]
> ```

You don't need the `AllowEncodedSlashes` directive since the encoded slashes are not in the URL-path (they are in the query string).

However, you do need to backslash-escape the literal `%` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string to prevent `%3` and `%2` being treated as backreferences (which don't exist - so are seen as empty strings - hence the missing characters in the rewritten URL, as seen in the Apache (debug) log).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/keycloak/logout$ /oauth2callback?logout=https\%3A\%2F\%2Fexample.com\%2Floggedout.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is 90% of the answer; thanks. There was one remaining issue, which is, I think, specific to `mod_auth_openidc`. It didn't seem to like the fact that the referer was `https://example.com/keycloak/logout` instead of just `https://example.com/`. I got around this by redirecting - the flags which work are `[R,QSA,NE]`, instead of `[QSA,L]`.

Comment: @QF0 "the referer was /keycloak/logout" - that's the requested URL (not strictly the "referer"). This is really an issue with how the request is picked up by (routed through) mod_auth_openidc. (Presumably there are other directives that handle this?) It's likely that the module is only looking at the requested URL (which is why an external redirect gets around it). However, you should still include the `L` flag here ie. `[R,QSA,NE,L]`.

Comment: Yes, I think `mod_auth_openidc` would have some way of handling this, but unfortunately setting it up is even more difficult than Apache rewrites. I've aded the `L`, thanks.